# nginx cant connect to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

nginx error log  says: `failed  (2: No such file or directory)` and i see a 404 error in the browser. I am getting *"welcome to nginx"* page when visiting my application homepage (`www.myapp.com`).

I've tried lot of configuration variants. Here's the current one:

config file

```
user  mo;
worker_processes  4;
error_log /opt/nginx/logs/error.log;
pid   /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
passenger_root /home/mo/gemshome/gems/passenger-4.0.2;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby193;

rails_env production;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
listen       80;
    server_name  www.myapp.com;
    root /home/mo/myapp/public;
passenger_enabled on;
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
```

Yet, i am not sure if rails production environment is set up correctly (corresponding line at nginx config file).

I followed all or most of the `phusion` HOWTOs.

Application works when I run the `webrick` server. So I assumed my app works, but that is being run on port `3000`  so i need  to know how to run `nginx` and `passenger` together.

Comment: I know this isn't your answer, but I used to use nginx only as a proxy to port 3000, using 'proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:3000"

Comment: can you link the passenger guide

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

We are using [**thin**](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) webserver. The `nginx` is configured to redirect all requests to the running `thin` instance and that is the secret.

The idea is:

- Rails is running at port, let's say, `3000`
- `nginx` handles all the statics at application' directory directly
- `nginx` redirects all requests *(which are not static ones)* to `localhost:3000`

### Example configurations

Here is `nginx` config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    client_max_body_size 800M;
    client_header_timeout 23m;
    client_body_timeout 23m;
    send_timeout 23m;

    root /home/user/myapp/public/;
    error_log /home/user/myapp/log/nginx_errors.log;
    access_log /home/user/myapp/log/nginx_access.log;

# One more statics route
#    location /assets/(.+-[a-z0-9]+\.\w+) {
#        root /home/user/myapp/public/assets/$1;
#        internal;
#    }

    location /images/(.+)(\?.*)? {
        root /home/user/myapp/public/images/$1;
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;

        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Sendfile-Type X-Accell-Redirect;

        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
        }

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `thin` config file:

```
chdir: /home/user/myapp/
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 1
daemonize: true
threaded: true
```

### Getting application with thin and nginx run

So, to run your application where `nginx` handles all the statics and nicely redirects you from `myapp.com` to your Rails application' instance, do the following:

1. Add `thin` gem dependency to your `Gemfile`: `gem 'thin'`
2. Install all the bundles: `bundle install`
3. Copy-and-paste and then edit the `nginx` config file to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf`
4. Enable your website for `nginx`: `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf`
5. Create your `thin` configuration file at `/etc/thin`, copy-and-paste content from this post and then correct it: `mkdir /etc/thin && touch /etc/thin/myapp.yml`
6. Install `thin` globally for your system: `thin install` (and then just follow the instructions)
7. Run `thin` and then run `nginx`: `/etc/init.d/thin start && /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

**NOTE:** do not forget to add a route to `/etc/hosts` if you are running the server locally and want to test your application on `myapp.com` domain:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.com
```

### Afterword

`nginx`, as far as I know, is mostly used as a proxy server or a statics-handling server. That happened because of its minimality and speed. `nginx` is really good at tasks like those.

Yet, `Phusion Passenger` is a really, really slow one. That I found out by myself at work. And that's why we switched to `thin`.

So my answer is based on my own experience, nothing more.

Still, you could use `passenger` instead of `thin` - `nginx` will still redirect you to your application. But it may take a lot more time to process your requests.

Hope this will help someone someday. Thank you for your question and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In your server block after the *passenger_enabled on* write  *rails_env development;* to the next line and remove the rails_env production; from the http block then reload the server.